# Where did this saying come from? " he/she wanted to know all the ins and outs of a cows backside"

Tags: etymology

This saying was in common use in our family. It was often said to me when I was asking too many questions. " For goodness sake you always want to know the ins and outs of a cows backside".

Comment: I never heard this one before, but my guess is it's a folksy American turn of phrase intended to euphemistically evoke the image of *a load of [old] **bull** [shit]*. I'm assuming it's common knowledge to rustics that bulls are interested in the back end of cows, and that *people aren't* (or at least, *shouldn't* be! :)

Comment: Not everything is a "saying". The idea is to invent new things and not just repeat old ones. It's called writing.

Comment: I've heard it once or twice, in the US Midwest.  I'm thinking it was from folks who tend to "collect" such "colorful" expressions, so it's not likely very common.

Comment: I've heard this said many times in a university kitchen in London  between 2005 and 2012, but only with "duck's arse" instead of "cows backside"

Answer (score 2):

It is an English expression (extremely vulgar) meaning, as it suggests, a nosey person who wants to know absolutely everything about a particular subject, or piece of gossip.  The digestive system of a cow is indeed complex, as they have three stomachs.  Thus the many 'ins and outs'.

Comment: It could have been more vulgar. I have certainly heard it used to put down someone who was excessively inquisitive - usually in the form of *he wants to know all the ins and outs of a cat's arse*.

Comment: A cat has only one stomach, therefore your expression has no basis in fact, and is merely a vulgarism.

Comment: Thank you Sinclair, it seems obvious now that you point it out the cow and its digestive process a ruminant; hence rumination - mid 17th cent.: from Latin ruminant- ‘chewing over again’. So asking time and time again chewing it over etc all seems very plausible. Many thanks.

Comment: @Sinclair A cow also only has one stomach, but that's fairly irrelevant. The number of ins and outs of its back side is unrelated to the number of stomachs it has—as long as it has only one back side, there's only one combined entry and exit. If anatomical accuracy were of any concern in sayings like these, it should be “the in and out of a cow’s back side”.

Answer (score 1):

It's British (as am I). More usually, we say

> I don't need to know the ins and outs of a duck's arse

Which is generally is used to mean

> I don't need every minute detail.

For example, a member of staff says to his boss

> I will go cut down that tree

and boss replies "ok". The employee then proceeds to tell the boss by which route he will take to get to the tree he is to cut down and the boss again replies "ok". The employee continues "I will go up the north path round the back of the lake and round the left aide of the hill to get to the tree", etc.

The boss does not need to know this level of detail, they just need to know the job is done and done in a proper and safe manner.  Therefore the phrase is a reference to detailed, useless information which will not benefit you in any way.

Bottom line, "I don't need to know the ins and outs of a duck's ass" is a colorful way of saying "I do not need to know all this detailed information".

In other words, you don't care what been put up there, nor do you care what has come out of there.

Comment: Another wrong animal. The expression this is confusing it with is 'He's as tight as a duck's arse' often followed by the unnecessary explanation '. . .and that's water-tight!' ('That's 'tight' in its Br-Eng sense of 'mean' . . .and, er, that's 'mean' in its Br-Eng sense of 'parsimonious' . . .)